# How can I setup Dropzone to a Smaller Area

Tags: dropzone.js, dropzone

I am using Dropzone code obtained from this web site

[DropZoneCode](https://codepedia.info/using-dropzone-js-file-image-upload-in-asp-net-webform-c)

In this example the dropzone is the width of the entire screen.  I would like to reduce that size down to about 400 to 500 pixel.  When I reduced the size of the div I could only drop 2 files before it stopped uploading files.  The 3rd file just opened in the browser, which I believe was an indication I was outside the  dropzone.

I believe if I reduced the size of the icon showing in the drop zone I would be able to add more files. Can anyone tell me where within the css file I can adjust the size of those items?

Comment: the css file is called dropzone.css, it must be on your root folder, and the properties to change the display is in the class  dz-preview, dz-image and dz-details I believe. And I don't think it stopped uploading the files, only that you can't see the third one for the reduced div.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working using this setup

```
 <asp:Panel ID="pnlStealthStat" runat="server" Visible="false">
            <div id="dZUpload" class="dropzone" style="height:auto;margin-top:5px;">
                <div class="dz-default dz-message"> Drop Stealth Stats Files Here</div>
            </div>
        </asp:Panel>
```

This setup was part of a bootstrap column and is functioning as expect